# Measure image sharpness with opencv using gpu

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, gpgpu

I created a small script that extract the most sharp image from a set of images using Laplacian like that:

```py
sharpness = cv2.Laplacian(cv2.imread(path), cv2.CV_64F).var()
```

However the code is a bit slow and it seems to only use CPU, then I'm wondering if there's a method that uses the gpu to calculate that value, but only find example to sharpen an image.

Comment: When you say slow - how slow, and for what image properties and numbers of images? How does it scale?

Comment: Everything is relative no ? I'm working on some thousand 4K images, it takes half a second per images, it's not so bad, I just wanted to see if it was possible to go faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't optimize before you **know what** is taking time.

Most time is spent on **loading** the image. Time it, you'll see. This involves accessing mass storage and decoding the image format. PNG isn't the most complex out there, so it could be worse.

The laplacian calculation uses [a specific kernel](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gad78703e4c8fe703d479c1860d76429e6). Convolving the picture with an arbitrary 3x3 kernel would cost 9 multiplications and 9 additions. *This* kernel costs one shift and five adds/subs. The CPU's SIMD will eat this for breakfast.

A GPU won't help at all. It takes time to *transfer* this data to the GPU. Then there are other constant costs (latency, "warm-up") to starting any calculations on a GPU. A CPU would already be done calculating. If you had a ton of pictures, at least the transfer could be pipelined and the upload of kernel code would only be required once.

Both the GPU and the CPU are likely memory-bound in this entire operation, meaning compute capability is far from challenged by this.

If you really wanted to get a GPU involved, the easiest way would be to wrap the numpy array in a `cv.UMat` and pass the UMat object in instead. OpenCV will then use OpenCL. The result will be a UMat again, so you would need to see what *OpenCV* function can calculate the variance for you.

```py
h_im = cv.imread(...) # hostside data
d_im = cv.UMat(im) # usable on "device"
d_lap = cv.Laplacian(d_im, cv.CV_32F) # single floats are usually faster than doubles
h_lap = d_lap.get() # retrieve data
# numpy functions unavailable on UMat, hence hostside calculation
var = h_lap.var()
# try cv.meanStdDev, calculates for each channel
```

Comment: Yes, that's not false, read time is near 0.25s and compute time around 0.3s, but that is still some margin. I will try to find how do do with gpu, not sure what you mean by "wrap the numpy array in a cv.UMat"...

Comment: granted, the exact numbers depend on the processor, and the specific picture. I happened to pick a few pictures from a random folder that took more to load than to process. I tried it on a few more and there loading takes less than the calculation. -- that's just `cv.Laplacian(cv.UMat(cv.imread(...)), cv.CV_32F).get().var()` single floats are a good idea because even if the CPU only has a 1:2 penalty for doubles, many GPUs have a worse penalty

Comment: `cv.Laplacian(cv.UMat(cv.imread(...)), cv.CV_32F).get().var()` works and compute time is now 0.08 ! I accepted your awser, maybe you could add your comment to the anwser. Thank you